# How to shuffle large text files efficiently while piping it on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, shuffle

I have a text file that is couple GBs. I am trying to shuffle this text file in a pipe.

For example these are some sample lines of what I am using but it is not efficient and in fact the pipe does not seem to start until the whole file is read. Maybe I am wrong on it.

```
shuf HUGETEXTFILE.txt|some command

cat HUGETEXTFILE.txt|sort -R |some command
```

I also tried to use

```
split -n 1/numberofchunks HUGETEXTFILE.txt|sort -R|some command
```

But the piping ends when the first chunk finishes.

I am trying to find an efficient way to pipe text file shuffling in a pipe because I do not want to write hundreds of files everytime I need a new way of shuffling, or random distribution.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use `shuf --input-range=$LO-$HI`? Instead of `split ...` you can give to `shuf` the range in linenumbers...

Comment: Well I amm trying to shuffle the whole file at once if possible. This just sounds like it would shuffle a range from the input file.

Comment: also that argument just creates bunch of random numbers,i am not sure if that is what I need. Can you be more elaborate please?

Comment: Have you tried using shuf with the --output option, then using cat outfile.txt | some command.  I know you said you didn't want to write hundreds of files, but this is only one and the name can be resued, meaning you should only have one.

Comment: You do know, that there simply is no "efficient" way to shuffle a multi-GB textfile (i.e. one, that doesn't fit in RAM) - shuffling is an intrinsicly expensive operation.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck, I do not mind if it is split in multiple ways in a script solution either. I just do not want to deal with many hundreds of files if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
cat bigfile.txt|
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo '%s\n' "$line" |shuf |sort -n| grep "sample";
  done
```

IFS is used to split the output into lines here.